# PHP Generate more than one string and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i'm currently making this little webshop application in PHP.

currently building a function that allows generating voucher codes.
this by itself works perfectly fine. although i'm not sure on how to generate more than one code and insert that to the database.

trying to educate myself on this.
so a helping hand would be amazing of course!

My code here:

```
<?php

    $page = "Gift Cards";
    require_once 'header.php'; 

    if(isset($_POST['createnewCard']))
    {
        $plan = $_POST['plan'];

        if(empty($plan))
        {
            $notify = error('Plan input was empty!');
        }

        if(empty($notify))
        {
             /// Generate Gift Code
            $code = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 10);

             /// Input to database
            $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `giftcards` VALUES(NULL, :code, :planID, 0, 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
            $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':code' => $code, ':planID' => $plan)); 

            $notify = success('New Giftcard has been generated. New code is: '.$code.'');
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: create a class and call the constructor

Comment: Do you want to create just a specific number of codes? You could do it in a loop. I would definitely at least abstracting this out to a helper function or helper class of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop:

```
for ($x=0; $x<5; $x++) {
     /// Generate Gift Code
     $code = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 10);

     /// Input to database
     $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `giftcards` VALUES(NULL, :code, :planID, 0, 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
     $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':code' => $code, ':planID' => $plan)); 

     $notify = success('New Giftcard has been generated. New code is: '.$code.'');
}
```

The loop executes 5 times (`$x<5`) and runs the code within the for loop each time. This will generate a new gift code each time and add it to the database.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

At first i think you have problems with your scoping. See variable $notify.

```
if(empty($notify))
{
    /// Generate Gift Code
    $code = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 10);

    ...
}
```

I agree with Aaron, i would do it just the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of abstracting this out.  You will need to clean it up for your case, but it should generate 5 codes.

```
<?php

    $page = "Gift Cards";
    require_once 'header.php'; 

    function generateCode() {
        if(isset($_POST['createnewCard']))
        {
            $plan = $_POST['plan'];

            if(empty($plan))
            {
                $notify = error('Plan input was empty!');
            }

            if(empty($notify))
            {
                 /// Generate Gift Code
                $code = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 10);

                 /// Input to database
                $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `giftcards` VALUES(NULL, :code, :planID, 0, 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
                $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':code' => $code, ':planID' => $plan)); 

                $notify = success('New Giftcard has been generated. New code is: '.$code.'');
            }   
        }
    }


    $numOfCodes = 5;

    for($i = 0; $i < $numOfCodes; ++$i) {
        generateCode();
    }
?>
```